# Connecting phpMyAdmin to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have been battling with this issue for the past day and a half, but as much as I enjoy troubleshooting, I figured its time to let someone here help me with this..

**Background**

So I am trying to deploy a server on EC2 with SQL and PHP, and to be more specific, server that runs *phpMyAdmin*.
I followed [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-lamp-amazon-linux-2.html) that basically explains the process, of which I made some changes. what I did in short:

- Initiated an EC2 instant (*amazon linux 2*)
- Initiated RDS database (*MariaDB*)
- Ran the EC2 instant as a web server (*Apache 2.4*)
- Used HTTPS with updated certification
- Download the most updated version of phpMyAdmin and extracted into 'www' folder
- Created an updated config.in.php file that contains the enpoint, user and password for the RDS database
- Used 'cookie as the auth method

Once I finished all of that (including some more steps that I don't think are important) I tried logging in only to get this: 
[image]

**What did I try?**

First thing I did was google (my best friend) and the first few suggestions that I saw were about the browser not storing the cookie correctly, so I cleared the cache, removed all cookies and tried again. I tried different browsers and they all ended with the same error message.

Other than that, I tried:

- I checked the inbound rules for both the database and the server, and both have access from HTTP, HTTPS, SSH and MySQL.
- Checked if it has something to do with the 'Public accessibility' and it had no effect
- I used different databases with no change

I probably tried some more obvious things that I failed to remember right now, but basically I am at a loss. I can of course change the auth method to 'config' but I want it to have a higher security.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

### TL;DR

Trying to connect to phpMyAdmin with EC2 instant and MariaDB on AWS. Can't log on to phpMyAdmin panel, with error 'Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS...'

Comment: Could you clarify what did you do? The tutorial you linked does not use RDS, but local mariadb installation. Also it does not use https. So how did you setup https - self-signed certificates?

Comment: Correct, I skipped that part and simply created RDS database. And the https is with the TLS connection as explained there ( it's with let's encrypt, not self signed)

Comment: Any reason you cannot use mysql workbench? Installing PHP My Admin is not advised on a remote endpoint

Comment: No reason, but I prefer using RDS. Why should the be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.. kinda.. 
Apparently using MariaDB is not working properly so after switching to MySQL I managed to connect successfully.

I will leave this question on in case someone else have a similar issue and this might be the solution.